# Symbolic links on Samba share

Tags: symlink, samba

I have a Samba share. Is there any way to determine from Windows side if a specific folder is a symlink or standard directory?

Comment: this is a real issue with samba and I would ask why some people have considered this question as off-topic. My answer is below.

Comment: This question is also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477814/check-if-symbolic-link-on-samba-share-with-python

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246322.aspx) this was not taken into account in the protocol specification. On that page you can see that there is no specification for the (symbolic) links.

I also tested with smbclient under Linux (Ubuntu) and there is no difference between links and directory.