# Check if symbolic link on Samba share with python

Tags: python, samba

Can I know with Python from Windows if some files that I have access to on a Samba share are "real" files or symbolic links ? I tried `os.path.islink` but it returns false as the documentation states:

> Always False if symbolic links are not supported

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2):

I used [pysmb](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb) to access samba shares from python and I found that according to the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246322.aspx) the (symbolic) link was not taken into account in the protocol specification.

I also tested with smbclient under Linux (Ubuntu) and there is no difference between links and directory.

So this seems to be a limitation of the samba specification.

PS: A [project of mine](https://github.com/undergraver/FileIndexer) aims to scan recursively a directory structure (samba share), which can loop forever in case of a symbolic link, since I cannot determine if it's a real directory or symbolic link.

Comment: That's what I feared! Thanks for taking the time to post an valuable answer. I won't mark it as accepted for now, since I hope someone finds a solution someday...