# Symlink on samba share ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, symlink, samba

I have tried to create symlinks on samba shared documents. for example 
i have shared test folder on samba it is access to all ,
if someone trying to create symlinks it shows this Error Msg -The target does not support symlinks

am using samba , ubuntu 12.04Lts changed smb.conf follow symlink and wide links to yes and unix extension = no

Any other way to support symlinks on samba share...

Comment: The Target Doesnot support symlinks inside the shared folder.

Comment: your question (about operating system) is not appropriate for this site, which is about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered to related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19036374/13136) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19036289/13136). The main idea is that samba doesn't support symlinks.

This means that if your samba server is on Linux the symlink will be seen as a directory / file and there is no way to tell if that is a symlink by browsing the samba share.